# How to add Headers to http request in Arduino IDE

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

This is the code in Arduino IDE that does not work (httpCode = -1):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

char ssid[] = "-------";
const char* password =  "------";

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting...");
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    HTTPClient http; //Object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/team/33/next/10");
    http.addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "-------");
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    Serial.println(httpCode);
    if (httpCode > 0) 
    {

      Serial.println(http.getString());

    }
    http.end(); //Close connection
  }
  delay(60000);
}
```

And here is the "exact" same code in python that works:

```
import requests

url = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/team/33/next/10"


headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "--------",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am veeeery new to programming in Arduino IDE, I only now python to be fair so my guess is that there are probably couple of mistakes in my code. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The arduino library I'm using doesn't send the additional headers on a GET unless it's wrapped in beginRequest() and endRequest()

```
http.beginRequest();
http.get(request->url);
http.sendHeader("x-rapidapi-key:" + request->apiKey);;
http.endRequest();
```

I was stuck on this way too long today.

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `addHeader` looks fine but it looks like you are trying to access a site over HTTPS/TLS.

The Arduino HTTP client needs a fingerprint/hash of the certificate that is used by the server. This is used in place of the usual validation of the certificate due to the CPU and memory constraints of an Arduino device.

You need to configure the certificate thumbprint for the `get` to work. e.g. define the fingerprint for the server's certificate

```
const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = { 0xe4, 0x5b, 0x13, 0x58, 0xc0, 0x4c, 0x27, 0xcb, 0x84, 0x4e,
                                  0xe1, 0xbb, 0x28, 0xf5, 0x36, 0x7c, 0x4f, 0x06, 0xa0, 0x1a };
```

Then supply this in the call to `begin()`

```
    http.begin("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/team/33/next/10",
               fingerprint);
```

I have not subscribed to the API on this platform so I get a valid 403 response when I try this:

```
09:23:13.550 -> 403
09:23:13.550 -> {"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}
```

Comment: one would expect HttpClient does it it parses https from the url